# I need a button code which work properly as my word

Tags: android, button, click

I have five button in a single activity. Starting four buttons is tapped 10  times only and then they disable. i need a code when these four buttons completely tapped by 10 times then 5th button is visible otherwise not. 
I want if every button is disable then  last button visible otherwise show toast.

Comment: Make the 5th button invisible. Maintain a counter for the four buttons and increment those counters each time the buttons are clicked. And when the counter become 10, make the 5th button visible.

Comment: This question shows zero research time. And zero intention in trying to solve himself.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, you need a variable to keep track of button clicks. Then make it increment each time a button is pressed with their onClickListener. On each click, with a simple if condition, verify if it's the 10th press. When this conditions finally become true, make your four buttons invisible and your fifth visible. It would be something like :

```
int buttonClicks = 0;

Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      buttonClicks++;
      if(buttonClicks==10) {
       button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       //for each button
       button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } //if
   } //onClick
} //onClickListener
```

For each of your buttons. I haven't tested it but you get the idea. Hope it helps

Comment: Suppose i have 4 task button (Task1,task2,task3,task4,result);  I need when all the 4 task is over then result button appears otherwise not.  OR if button is visible ,if all the task is not completed then result button not work or show Toast " Complete all the tasks".